# Is there a way to check if the mouse is clicked on a certain element in p5.js

Tags: javascript, click, p5.js

So what I am trying to do is make a clicker game, yet when I use the standard:

```js
let Coins = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400)
}
//draws the circle
function draw() {
  background(100)
  circle(200, 200, 50)
  //creates the text to show the amount of coins
  text(Coins, 200 - (textWidth(Coins) / 2), 150)
}
//detects when the mouse is pressed
function mouseClicked() {
  //changes the number of coins
  Coins = Coins + 1
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I can click anywhere and it will count up the Coins, but I want it so that if the mouse is On the shape/element it will then count.
I don't want to use the "If (mouseX => width / 2)" but just know when the mouse is over/hovering over the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In p5js you need to implement ["hit testing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing) yourself. In this case you can do so by checking if the distance between the mouse and the center of the coin is less than the radius of the coin.

```js
let Coins = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400)
}

let coinPosition = new p5.Vector(200, 200);
let coinRadius = 25;

//draws the circle
function draw() {
  background(100)
  push()
  if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, coinPosition.x, coinPosition.y) <= coinRadius) {
    fill('gold')
  }
  circle(coinPosition.x, coinPosition.y, coinRadius * 2)
  // restore the previous fill value
  pop()
  //creates the text to show the amount of coins
  text(Coins, 200 - (textWidth(Coins) / 2), 150)
}
//detects when the mouse is pressed
function mouseClicked() {
  if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, coinPosition.x, coinPosition.y) <= coinRadius) {
    //changes the number of coins
    Coins = Coins + 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way for it to be a universal shape, like a custom polygon or a 3d shape?

Comment: For more complex shapes you will need to implement a [point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithm. [Here](https://editor.p5js.org/Kumu-Paul/sketches/kyu5SRqKp) is an example I wrote using p5js. To make this work with splines (curves, bezier curves, etc) would be similar but require more math. For hit testing with 3d shapes you'll need to implement [ray casting](https://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html).